# NOT able to turn off the bluetooth when android api level is 33 and Android OS is 13 but the same code is working on andorid 13 with API 31

Tags: android, android-13, android-api-33

NOT able to turn off the bluetooth when android api level is 33 and Android OS is 13 but the same code is working on andorid 13 with API 31

```
public void toggleBluetooth(boolean enable) { try{ if (enable && !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { final int BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_CODE = 1;           
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)
                       != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    
                   Log.e("AUTOTEST_BLUETOOTH","DENIED");
    
                   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                           new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_CODE);
               }
    
               if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
                       != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   Log.e("AUTOTEST_BLUETOOTH","DENIED");`your text`
                   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                           new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH}, BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_CODE);
               }
               bluetoothAdapter.enable();
           } else if (!enable && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
               Log.e("AUTOTEST_BLUETOOTH","DISABLED");
               bluetoothAdapter.disable();
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Log.e("BLUETOOTH_EXCEPTION",e.getMessage());
       }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your observation is the expected outcome and is so [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#disable()) accordingly.